# Rust String AsRef<T> does not auto borrow for [u8]

Tags: rust

Rust String implements both [AsRef<str>](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2575) and [AsRef<[u8]>](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2591)

But why does Rust correctly allow String to be borrowed as **&str** but not as **&[u8]** even when we provide explicit type annotation hint?

```rust
let s = String::from("hello");
let item: &str = &s; // Works
let item2: &[u8] = &s; // Fails
```

Ofcourse explicit invocation works, but curious why above doesn't work

```rust
let item2: &[u8] = s.as_ref();
```

Comment: You're using [std::string::String::borrow()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/str.rs.html#206) not AsRef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a `&String` coerces to `&str`, that happens via the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait (not `AsRef`, and not `Borrow`). The `Deref` trait is not generic — it only allows *one* type to be chosen to “dereference to”. In the case of `String`, that's `str`.

The `AsRef` and `Borrow` traits are *not special to the compiler*. They are available for generic code to use *explicitly*, not implicitly.

Comment: I thought you needed `*` for deref, or else use auto deref, which is only for methods? I could be wrong, but then I don't know how hashmaps work

Comment: Understand deref works well for owned value and for String, str is the underlying owned value, but shouldnt deref trigger when using . or * operator. In above case & is a ref so I would think asref or asborrow should get invoked not deref?

Comment: `Deref` is considered for `.` and `*` as well as for conversion from `&T` to `&U`. It is the only trait that does that. `AsRef` and `Borrow` are not special and therefore can only be used explicitly (via `.as_ref()` and `.borrow()`)